# Why am I getting the word undefined when I run changeword.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, undefined

So , I was trying to make for my website an automatic way that the words can change, It almost worked , but idk why I get the word "undefined"; Can you please help?https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss9wg.jpg

```js
var words = ['affordable.', 'fast.', 'easy.', 'different.'],
    element = document.getElementById('wordChange'),
    currentWord = 0;

window.setInterval(function () {
    currentWord++;
    if (currentWord > words.length) currentWord = 0;
    element.innerHTML = words[currentWord];
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>ColorBundle | Welcome</title>
    <!--BOOTSTRAP-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/style.css">
    <!--GOOGLE FONTS-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Odibee+Sans|Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--
        font-family: 'Odibee Sans', cursive;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        font-family: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;
    -->
</head>

<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="nav-brand">
            <h1>ColorBundle</h1>
        </div>
        <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
        <div class="menu">
            <a href="#">HOME</a>
            <div class="menu-mobile-border"></div>
            <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
            <div class="menu-mobile-border"></div>
            <a href="#">WORKS</a>
            <div class="menu-mobile-border"></div>
            <a href="#">SERVICES</a>
            <div class="menu-mobile-border"></div>
            <a href="#">BLOG</a>
            <div class="menu-mobile-border"></div>
            <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
            <div class="menu-mobile-border"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="top-img">
        <h2><span id="wordChange">creative.</span></h2>
    </div>




    <script src="./script/changeword.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Can you please help me solve this problem? I know it's not that big of a deal but I am curious what is from

Comment: Maybe you click on what the tags say, such as "undefined" before assigning them to your question -- the answer's right there, or at least a clue

Comment: Arrays are 0 based, you need to loop back to 0 when the `currentWord >= words.length`

Comment: And move `currentWord++` to be the last line in the function because you are skipping `0`, which is the first item in the array.

Answer (score 3):

You iterate over array, so indexes starts at 0. While `words.length` gives you index+1

So your `currentWord > words.length` is out of bounds.

Do `if (currentWord >= words.length)`

Answer (score 1):

Arrays start from `index 0` so by doing

```
currentWord > words.length
```

you go to `index 4` which doesnt exist. 
You can fix this by doing

```
currentWord >= words.length
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

1) Your condition needs to properly check the length of the array (which is 0-index-based) so change `currentWord > words.length` to `currentWord >= words.length`.

2) You immediately increase the counter so that the first word you see is at index 1, so you might want to move the counter increment to the bottom of the function.

```js
var words = ['affordable.', 'fast.', 'easy.', 'different.'],
    element = document.getElementById('wordChange'),
    currentWord = 0;

window.setInterval(function () {
    if (currentWord >= words.length) currentWord = 0;
    element.innerHTML = `${currentWord}${words[currentWord]}`;
    ++currentWord;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="wordChange"/>
```